# Median Standard Deviation with mad()

Tags: matlab, median

I'm using matlabs `mad()` function to find the median standard deviation. `mad(X)` returns an expected value, 237.2147. However, `mad(X,1)` which according to the documentation should find median standard deviation just returns 1 no matter the input.

Any ideas very much appreciated,

Thanks

**Edit**
The input is a single column of Doubles:

```
5
16
7
4
6
4
8
6
9
6
7
9
19
3
8

Trial>> mad(dM)

ans =

  206.1872

Trial>> mad(dM,1)

ans =

     1
```

Comment: What is your input vector? You will need to provide us a [mcve]

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the built-in `mad`? Based on the data you're passing it, the outputs don't match. Check which `mad` you're using with `which('mad')`

Comment: Oh sorry, the answers aren't from the data I've given. That is just a sample.

Comment: and which('mad') gives Applications/MATLAB_R2016a.app/toolbox/stats/stats/mad.m

Comment: Ok you need to give us data that we can run that replicates your issue.

Comment: What is the best way to do that? It's 50k records long?

Comment: Have you checked that the result *shouldn't* be 1? Try this: `median(abs(dM-median(dM)))`

Comment: Yes that does also give the result 1.

Comment: Everything is working as expected then. It uses the median so removing a single outlier is unlikely to have an effect